# Styling a textarea resizer block

Tags: css

I am trying to create a styled textarea, for this it is 99% done, but one final thing remains. The resize icon on the bottom right, I know in wekbit based browsers you have `textarea::-webkit-resizer`, but I cannot find anything for firefox / IE etc.

If anyone can help with this, it is greatly appreciated.

My example code is:

SCSS:

```
textarea.myTextArea {
    background-color: $my-color;
    border: 0;

    &::-webkit-resizer {
        background-image: url('images/myimage.svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: I only know of https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea for styling it equally across different browsers.

Comment: As much as possible, any JavaScript styling is to be avoided - we are trying to avoid the FOUC that gives...

Comment: But the `resize` property is not supported in any version of IE including Edge. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)

Comment: I understand that, but the system in question is rather large and anything with the chance to affect load times etc. is to be avoided at all costs...

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to style the resize-handler in Firefox. The `resize` property is still a W3C CSS3 draft (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize#Specifications or https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#resize). So you either go full and save performance by not using draft properties, deal with issues like you're facing now, or use external libraries to mimic it and affecting page load time. (FOUC can be avoided by hiding the page content until everything is loaded - using callbacks if possible and not `window.load`.)

Answer (score 1):

*To put it as an answer:*

The CSS3-property `resize` is not supported in any version of IE - including Edge. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)

As far as I know it's not possible to style the resize-handler in Firefox. The resize property is still a W3C CSS3 draft (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize#Specifications or https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#resize).
So you either go full and save performance by not using draft properties, deal with issues like you're facing now, or use external libraries to mimic it and affecting page load time.

As a side note: [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) can be avoided or more specifically "concealed" by hiding the page content until everything is styled accordingly - e.g. with using callbacks and avoiding *window.load* if possible.

---

A good JS library I know of to accomplish cross-browser resizable textareas (and other elements) is https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, the resize property is not really cared about as such, it's the resizer icon thing that appears in the bottom right of a textarea.

Comment: If you just want to hide the icon - and are ok with disabling the resize - do `resize:none`. Browsers that support resizing of textareas will disable that feature resulting in having no handler-icon.

Comment: And that's what I'm telling you: First, the resize feature is not available in all browsers, because it's only a draft feature as of now. Second, you can only customize the icon in webkit based browsers - hence not in Firefox.

Comment: So you only have those three options: 1) Living with icons you can not customize. Or 2) Disabling the feature and therefor get rid of the icons you can't fully control. Or 3) Use a javascript library to enable full customization and full browser support. -- You don't want to use JS (option 3), because of page load time increase and possible FOUC. It seems you don't want to disable the feature (option 2). So there's only one option left: deal with it (option 1).