# Change resize icon style using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Is this possible to change the default resize icon.

::-webkit-resizer{
 // adding styles`enter code here`
}

this is not working

Comment: As far as I know you can try    `#div_of_element::-webkit-resizer` but I don't think you change its width!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling a textarea resizer block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785868/styling-a-textarea-resizer-block)